# Leaflet Layer control suitable for touch device (to expand on click instead of hover)

Tags: javascript, dom, leaflet

I have a difficulty to get the Leaflet Layer Control to work on a touch device.
Currently, the control expands/collapses correctly when mouseenter/mouseleave the cog icon. But a touch device cannot act on hover.

[image]

Hence, I would like to toggle the control on icon click.
Is this actually supported by the control?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032224/leaflet-layer-control-open-only-on-click) suggets invoking the toggle function but this does not work for me because there is no function called *toggle* on the object (only *expand* and *collapse*).

I did the following hack in my own floorplan component to test: If I make the leaflet instance
global `window['layerControl'] = this.layerControl;` I can later on in the Chrome DevTools Console toggle the control by executing `layerControl.expand();` and `layerControl.collapse();`

However, this is a hack and I still need to wire those functions to the toggle button.
What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added click behavior to the layerControl as follows:

```
const layerContainer = this.layerControl.getContainer();
const layerControl = this.layerControl as any;

// Add a toggle method to the control
layerControl.toggle = () => {
    // Check the classname to avoid introducing extra state
    layerContainer.className.includes('expanded')
            ? layerControl.collapse()
            : layerControl.expand();
    };
// In L.Control.LayersOptions I needed to set collapsed to false, hence collapse it programatically
layerControl.collapse();

// Add the toggle method like created above as a click hander
layerContainer.addEventListener('click', () => layerControl.toggle());
```